# Can't put row above tableheader

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I made a custom row and want to put it above the table header. [image]How can i do this? [see custom row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWsWk.png) , I got this from the example, can anyone please help me? here my code :

```
doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
                                theme : 'grid',
                                styles: {
                                   halign: 'right'
                                },
                                headerStyles: {
                                   fillColor: [33, 150, 243],
                                   halign:'center'
                                },
                                margin : {
                                  top : 100
                                },
                                columnStyles:{
                                     0: {halign:'left'}
                                },
                                 createdCell: function(cell, data) {
                                        if (data.row.index === 0 || data.row.index === 3 ||data.row.index === 6 ||data.row.index === 9 
                                                || data.row.index === 12 || data.row.index === 13 || data.row.index === 14) {

                                          cell.styles.fontStyle = 'bold';
                                          cell.styles.fillColor = [255,251,204];
                                        }
                                },
                                 drawRow: function (row, data) {
                                        // Colspan
                                        doc.setFontStyle('bold');
                                        doc.setFontSize(20);
                                        if (row.index === 0) {
                                            doc.setTextColor(200, 0, 0);
                                            doc.rect(data.settings.margin.left, row.y, data.table.width, 20, 'S');
                                            doc.autoTableText("Raportage Handelsregister", data.settings.margin.left + data.table.width / 2, row.y + row.height / 2, {
                                                halign: 'center',
                                                valign: 'middle',

                                            });
                                            data.cursor.y += 20;
                                        } 
                                 }
                            });
```

Comment: Can you also include in the question what the actual problem is? Ie what the pdf looks like when run with the code above.

Comment: @SimonBengtsson i added the photo, you can take a look at it with this code given above

Comment: Have you tried simple printing a rectangle with some text on it with the addPageContent hook?

Comment: No i did not try it? Do you have a example on this... I looked at the example but i don't understand it. I really am getting used to this now